# Empty Array is Returned Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I am new at JavaScript, and I am coding for a challenge a function that receives an array of arrays representing parking spots, and a string with type of the vehicle that is looking for a parking spot. For each type of car, an upper-case letter means that the particular spot is AVAILABLE.
The function must return an array with the coordinates of the spot as an [X, Y] pair.

Here is what I coded so far:

```
const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) => {
let tmp = [];
  for(let k=0; k<spots.length; k++){
    for(let j=0; j<spots[k].length ; j++){
      switch(vehicle){
        case 'regular': if(spots[k][j]==='R') tmp.push([k,j]); continue;
        case 'small': if(spots[k][j]==='S') tmp.push([k,j]); continue;
        case 'motorcycles': if(spots[k][j]=== 'M') tmp.push([k,j]); continue;
      }
    } 
  } 
  return tmp;
}
```

When I print my array, it is empty. Anyone can help me out ?

EDIT: here is the test case:

```
const spots = [
      // COLUMNS ARE X
      //    0    1    2    3    4    5
          ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 1
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm'], // 2
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 3
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 4
          ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S'], // 5
      ]

      const vehicle = 'regular' // possible options are 'regular', 'small', or 'motorcycle'
```

**output should be [4,0]**

my tmp array currently prints: []

Comment: since you are modifying the original value of tmp, shouldn't it be a `let` instead of a `const`?

Comment: Would you mind printing the `spots` and `vehicle` arrays? Thanks.

Comment: @MarceloF. he's not modifying the reference of `tmp`, so using `const` is fine and what he should be using. He's modifying the *contents* of `tmp`.

Comment: @MarceloF. When you're adding to an array or object you're not re-assigning or re-declaring the constant, it's already declared and assigned, you're just adding to the "list" that the constant points to,so it should work fine.

Comment: @Jamie I printed the spots and vehicle

Comment: @Ibraheem I am not sure to understand, length=6 is never going to be reached anyways because of the "<" operator. Do you mind explaining why spots.length wouldn't work?

Comment: @codeBarrel yes you're right sorry it's been a long day.

Answer (score 0):

```
const spots = [
  ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // spots[0], spots[0][0] === 's', spots[0][3] === 'S', spots[0][5] === 'M'
  ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // spots[1]
  ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm'], // spots[2]
  ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // spots[3]
  ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // spots[4]
  ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S'], // spots[5] and spots.length === 6
]

const vehicle = 'regular' // possible options are 'regular', 'small', or 'motorcycle'

const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) => {
  let tmp = [];
  for (let k = 0; k < spots.length; k++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < spots[k].length; j++) {
      switch (vehicle) {
        case 'regular':
          if (spots[k][j] === 'R') tmp.push([k, j]);
          continue;
        case 'small':
          if (spots[k][j] === 'S') tmp.push([k, j]);
          continue;
        case 'motorcycles':
          if (spots[k][j] === 'M') tmp.push([k, j]);
          continue;
      }
    }
  }
  return tmp;
}

const output = whereCanIPark(spots, vehicle);

console.log(output);
```

Output:
[[0, 4], [1, 4], [2, 4], [3, 4], [4, 4]]

See:
https://jsfiddle.net/uqygj65h/

And BTW, "rows" are 'X' ie the first dimension of spots. "columns" will be the second dimension, i.e spots[row][column]. I've edited your comments to show this.

Another point - 'm' is different to 'M', i.e 'm' !== 'M'. If you want to ignore the case then perhaps do `if (spots[k][j].toUpperCase() === 'M')`.

Your function written using `Array.reduce`:

```
const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) =>
  spots.reduce((acc, level, levelIndex) => {
    level.forEach((space, spaceIndex) => {
      if (
        (vehicle === 'regular' && space.toUpperCase() === 'R') ||
        (vehicle === 'small' && space.toUpperCase() === 'S') ||
        (vehicle === 'motorcycles' && space.toUpperCase() === 'M')
      )
        acc.push([levelIndex, spaceIndex]);
    });
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

You can write it even more concisely but you should be able to see how the reduce and forEach functions work from that.

Extra homework:

```
  if (
    (vehicle === 'regular' && space.toUpperCase() === 'R') ||
    (vehicle === 'small' && space.toUpperCase() === 'S') ||
    (vehicle === 'motorcycles' && space.toUpperCase() === 'M')
  )
```

can be written as:
`if (vehicle[0].toUpperCase() === space.toUpperCase())`

And some more homework, using brackets and the comma operator, the function becomes:

```
const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) =>
  spots.reduce((acc, level, levelIndex) =>
    (level.forEach((space, spaceIndex) => {
      if (vehicle[0].toUpperCase() === space.toUpperCase()) acc.push([levelIndex, spaceIndex]);
    }), acc), []);
```

Just noticed your upper case array item is intentional, marking the spot as available. I should have read your question better. In that case, you would just compare the array item value itself without changing it to upper case:

```
const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) =>
  spots.reduce((acc, level, levelIndex) =>
    (level.forEach((space, spaceIndex) => {
      if (vehicle[0].toUpperCase() === space) acc.push([levelIndex, spaceIndex]);
    }), acc), []);
```

Good luck learning JavaScript. Take a look at TypeScript once you get comfortable, and "You Don't Know JavaScript Yet" is a great read.

Answer (score 0):

I can't leave a comment and I am not chasing to be marked an answer. Just looking to help out.
So, here we go:

My best guess there is something wrong with the how you call whereCanIPark. The code below just works for me.

```
    const spots = [
  // COLUMNS ARE X
  //    0    1    2    3    4    5
  ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
  ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 1
  ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm'], // 2
  ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 3
  ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 4
  ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S'], // 5
]

const vehicle = 'regular';
const tmp = [];
for (let k = 0; k < spots.length; k++) {
  for (let j = 0; j < spots[k].length; j++) {
    switch (vehicle) {
      case 'regular': if (spots[k][j] === 'R') tmp.push([k, j]); continue;
      case 'small': if (spots[k][j] === 'S') tmp.push([k, j]); continue;
      case 'motorcycles': if (spots[k][j] === 'M') tmp.push([k, j]); continue;
    }
  }
}
console.error(tmp);
```

Also, an advice:

Do not put Loop in the loop - make a method.

Method must do one thing, if it is doing two -> make another method.

In your code, I would made at least 3 different methods.

It helps readability and the debug in general.

The code is full of magic strings -  'regular','motorcycles' . Create 3 variables to represent those.

Code style matter. It will make you life so much easier. 
You could then just check output of each method and pin point where exactly the bug is.

After you found your bug, check out:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

If you use it, it will make the code prettier in general.

Comment: And to add further, check out the JS `Array.reduce` method which will mean you won't need to define a `tmp` array.

Answer (score 0):

you can do that

```js
const spots = [
      // COLUMNS ARE X
      //    0    1    2    3    4    5
          ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 0 ROWS ARE Y
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 1
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm'], // 2
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 3
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 4
          ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S'], // 5
      ]
const vehicle = 'regular'  

const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) => 
  {
  let tmp    = []
    , letter = {regular: 'R', small:'S', motorcycles: 'M' }[vehicle]
    ;
  spots.forEach((e,x)=>
    {
    let y = -1
    while ((y = e.indexOf(letter,++y))>=0) tmp.push([x,y])
    });
  return tmp;
  }

document.write( JSON.stringify ( whereCanIPark(spots, vehicle) ))
```

you can also do:

```js
const spots = 
        [ [ 's', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M' ] 
        , [ 's', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M' ] 
        , [ 's', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm' ] 
        , [ 'S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M' ] 
        , [ 'S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M' ] 
        , [ 'S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S' ] 
        ] 
  ,   vehicle = 'regular' 
  ,   option  = { regular: 'R', small:'S', motorcycles: 'M' }
  ,   jojo = spots.reduce((a,c,x)=>
        {
        let y = -1
        while ((y=c.indexOf(option[vehicle],++y))>-1) a.push([x,y])
        return a
        },[])
document.write ( JSON.stringify ( jojo ))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a couple of assumptions:

- That you got your output array in the wrong order (you want the way it is access in the array, i.e. [0,4] and not [4,0]). If that is incorrect, just wap the order of the two items in the array.
- You seem to want the first valid spot -- not the whole list. If this is true, leave the `[0]` at the end. If not, you can remove that for the full list.
- The set of letters and vehicle types you provided was exhaustive and representative of all the possible strings you could be working with. If that is not accurate, you may need to revisit the rules for checking "validity" of a space.

```js
const whereCanIPark = (spots, vehicle) => {
  return spots.flatMap(
    (row, rowIdx) => spots[rowIdx].map(
      (val, colIdx) => val === vehicle[0].toUpperCase()
        ? [rowIdx, colIdx] : false, // Note: If you want the other order, just swap row/col in the array -- but this matches reality in their array position.
    )
  ).filter(Boolean)[0]; // Your question seems to imply you want "the first available space".
}


const spots = [
      // COLUMNS
      //    0    1    2    3    4    5
          ['s', 's', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 0 ROWS
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'M'], // 1
          ['s', 'M', 's', 'S', 'R', 'm'], // 2
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 3
          ['S', 'r', 's', 'm', 'R', 'M'], // 4
          ['S', 'r', 'S', 'M', 'M', 'S'], // 5
      ];

console.log(
  whereCanIPark(spots, 'regular')
);
```